# What to do with "There was a problem enabling iCloud Backup" on iPad?

Tags: ipad, ios

I just upgraded to iOS 5 on my iPad and during the intro session it asks you if you want to "back up to iCloud".  Choosing yes, gives the error "There was a problem enabling iCloud Backup".  Any ideas?

Comment: I think it might be that you don't have enough space to fit the entire backup (by default only 5 Gb), but I'm just guessing

Comment: @ivo no, I have nothing on my iPad

Comment: I've had this problem intermittently during the betas as well. Often it just required me to go back into settings, switch off the backup, and then switch it back on.

Comment: I tried that several times and kept getting the same error @Diago

Comment: My guess is that this is probably an intermittent problem due to the initial demand for iCloud/initial backups everyone is making.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [iCloud System Status page](http://www.apple.com/support/icloud/systemstatus/) lists several problems on 13 October.

Others have said they had the same problem, so maybe one of the troubleshooting pages linked from the [iCloud Backup Support](http://www.apple.com/support/icloud/backup/) page might help?

Later: Yes, it does help. [this linked page 'iCloud: troubleshooting creating backups'](http://support.apple.com/kb/TS3992) lists specific error messages and says of yours:

> "There was a problem enabling iCloud Backup."
>
> There are various reasons that this can occur. If you receive this alert, wait and try again later. If you receive a more specific alert message as well, make any required adjustments and try again. If you continue to receive this generic alert, [contact iCloud Support for assistance.](http://www.apple.com/support/icloud/ww/)